# Simplest of parsers in go tool yacc

Tags: go, yacc

Using this command:

```
go tool yacc -p Verb -o verb.go boilerplate.y
```

Trying to build this yacc file:

```
// boilerplate.y
%{

package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "unicode"
)

%}

%% 

.|\n   ECHO;

%%

func main() {
    fi := bufio.NewReader(os.NewFile(0, "stdin"))
  s, err := fi.ReadString('\n')
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println('error', err)
  } 

  VerbParse(&VerbLex{s: s})
}
```

Error: `bad syntax on first rule: boilerplate.y:16`

Successfully got this example to work:

https://github.com/golang-samples/yacc/blob/master/simple/calc.y

Trying to build my own and work through the lex & yacc book.  Resources seem limited to non existent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have an incorrect `rule` in your specifications.

A specification file has the following declaration:

```
declarations
%%
rules
%%
programs
```

Where a `rule` is defined as:

```
A  :  BODY  ;
```

Where **A** is a non-terminal symbol, while **BODY** is made up of tokens (terminal symbols), non-terminals and literals. The `:` and `;` are required components of rule declaration syntax.

Hence the rule:

```
.|\n   ECHO;
```

is syntactically incorrect.

Since you are simply trying to echo the input, a very simple implementation based on `calc.y` would be following (file *echo.y*):

**rules**

```
%%

in : /* empty */
  | in input '\n'
     { fmt.Printf("Read character: %s\n", $2) }
  ;

input : CHARACTER
  | input CHARACTER
      { $$ = $1 + $2 }
  ;
```

**program**

```
%%

type InputLex struct {
    // contains one complete input string (with the trailing \n)
    s string
    // used to keep track of parser position along the above imput string
    pos int
}

func (l *InputLex) Lex(lval *InputSymType) int {
    var c rune = ' '

    // skip through all the spaces, both at the ends and in between
    for c == ' ' {
        if l.pos == len(l.s) {
            return 0
        }
        c = rune(l.s[l.pos])
        l.pos += 1
    }

    // only look for input characters that are either digits or lower case
    // to do more specific parsing, you'll define more tokens and have a 
    // more complex parsing logic here, choosing which token to return
    // based on parsed input
    if unicode.IsDigit(c) || unicode.IsLower(c) {
        lval.val = string(c)
        return CHARACTER
    }

    // do not return any token in case of unrecognized grammer
    // this results in syntax error
    return int(c)
}

func (l *InputLex) Error(s string) {
    fmt.Printf("syntax error: %s\n", s)
}

func main() {
    // same as in calc.y
}

func readline(fi *bufio.Reader) (string, bool) {
    // same as in calc.y
}
```

To compile and run this program, do the following at command prompt:

```
go tool yacc -o echo.go -p Input echo.y
go run echo.go
```

As you can see, you'll have to define your own parsing rules in the `Lex` method. The struct `InputLex` is designed to hold the values while your input is being parsed. `InputSymType` is auto generated and is defined by the `%union` declared in the `declaration` part of specification.

As far as I can tell, there is no way to directly use JISON or a regex to do the matching using go's `yacc` tool. You may have to take a look at some other libraries.

More details can be found here: http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/yacc/

Full working code here: https://play.golang.org/p/u1QxwRKLCl

Comment: I just want a basic file to echo standard input.  I only kind of know JISON, and in that there are lex rules and grammar rules.  I wanted to see the two broken out using Go in a .y file that I can work on to rebuild the simple calc file, then maybe a json parser or something.

Comment: Here is JISON using lex rules in the same file:  http://zaa.ch/jison/demos/calc/  I don't really grok how having a lex function works that you linked.  I see breaking the lex stage into tokens using reg ex.

Comment: Added a basic echo parser. As far as I can tell, JISON might not be usable with go tool's yacc.

Comment: You are right about one thing though. There is a severe lack of proper documentation.

Comment: TIL: Just use ANTLR :)   Someone recently got a go target mostly working.

Answer (score -2):

All yacc grammar file shoud have 3 parts

- declarations
- rules
- programs

in Declarations,  you may has `%token, %type, %start`, indicate token list, nonterminal list and the start symbol in grammar.

rule's form is `A:Body {action codes}`

programs need implement the function lexer or getToken

see the example https://github.com/acekingke/yaccgo/blob/main/examples/e.y

it is easy to understand, just parse the string "nnn..."